# Track individual via Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Analytics.  I have a conversion set up, and I'd like to capture demographics for individuals who convert at e individual level.  When a user converts, I'd like to pass the statistics from Google Analytics into my own database, or keep a record of the ID assigned at conversion in Google Analytics and download the data.  Is this possible?  I want to do analysis on who is likely to convert versus not - age, shopping habits, etc - and link these details back to the type of specific conversion.

Thoughts?

Comment: The first thought is that you need to take not to violate Googles Termin of Service, which state that you must not store data that identifies a user in Google Analytics (it's okay though to store an id that lets you match GA data to data stored in a 3rd party system). Combining Google Analytics Demographics with segments that cover indivual users will most probably not work (GA usally does not display demographic data for very small groups of users). Plus check what the laws of your country have to say about profile building (e.g. in Europe you need the consent of the user).

Comment: I am in the US.  I do not have a User ID yet.  These are new sessions, unauthenticated.  I know Google knows in general some demographic info by IP or some method.  I want to know the demographics of who is performing some action on the site , and I want the demographics in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

We if want to add add track users at individual level, try creating a Custom diamension and passing the userID everytime you make a GA call. 
Next to view the same :- in tables that you view your analytics data, there will be this option called 'Secondary diamention', from the list that appears.. Choose the custom diamension name that you had assigned. Now you will be able to see each row with the userID along slide.

Comment: This will not work with small amount of users (I think below 100 per segment), so usecase with demographic reports will not work with this solution. And it is probably againts Google TOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Add user ID to your tracking script**

The first step to your question is to add the user ID to your tracking. If you have some way to identify users on your website (ie: through email marketing tool, your CRM, etc), then you should set up user ID tracking. Here is the Google Dev article about that:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en

However, basically... you just have to add this to your tracking script (replacing the 'create' line you currently have, replacing "USER_ID" with the user ID your system gives them.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', { 'userId': USER_ID });
```

In addition, I usually include this UserID as a custom dimension, so that I can view it in Google Analytics and other reports. To do this, first set up a custom dimension for your ID, as a "User-level" dimension. Then just add this after your user ID is available (assuming this is your first custom dimension):

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', USER_ID);
```

**Connect User ID to Demographics**

Unfortunately, the demographics information that Google Analytics provides (under "Audience") is not compatible with custom dimensions (like userID). So, the API only allows you to pull the audience data in aggregate (ie: connected to City, number of users, pageviews of those types of people... etc). If this works for you, check out the GA Query Explorer (below) to try out different combinations of dimensions & metrics to drill down as deep as you can and maximize the information you gain from this demographic info.

**Connect Google Analytics Data to Your Database**

In order to connect GA data to your database in an automated fashion, you will need to set up some kind of scheduled process that runs a query off of the Google Analytics API. To explore what combinations of metrics and stuff are available, I'd suggest checking out the [Google Analytics API Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and the [Google Analytics API reference material](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). What I did was set up an SSIS package (using [SSIS GoogleAnalyticsSource](https://analyticssource.codeplex.com/)) as the data source, which made it fairly easy. Then just scheduled that to run daily, populating the data I want into my database.

Alternatively, you could download less complicated reports directly from Google Analytics and import them into your database with something like SQL Server Management Studio.